# res.status.json() is not a function in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, next-api

I am creating this api endpoint called pincode.js in Nextjs:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status.json([234400, 721302, 110003, 560017]);
}
```

but it is giving the error : res.status.json() is not a function
How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

status is a function that expects a status code, you should call or omit it.

passing status 200 to it:

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json([234400, 721302, 110003, 560017]);
}
```

omit status code, and send default one (200, if I'm not mistaken):

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.json([234400, 721302, 110003, 560017]);
}
```